# Working with MySQL & PHP in Android

Tags: java, android, mysql

I'm trying to make a App which can add data into my database.I have a Table which have two columns "Name" and "Points".So I made a PHP file and uploaded into my server :

```
<?php 

    $connection = mysql_connect("mywebhost.example", "user", "password")ordie(mysql_error());
    $selection = mysql_select_db("name_of_database", $connection)or die(mysql_error());

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $points = $_POST['points'];

    $insert = "INSERT INTO my_table('name','points') VALUES('$name','$points')";
    $run = mysql_query($insert)or die(mysql_error());

?>
```

I uploaded this in

> ftp://mywebhost.example/android_connect/connect.php

Now I tried to connect it with my App like this :

```
public void test_button (View view)
{
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("country", country));
    try {
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://mywebhost.example/android_connect/connect.php");
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Sooo... When I try to test it my App crashs and gives me this Error :

```
    03-15 12:08:34.409: E/AndroidRuntime(626): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-15 12:08:34.409: E/AndroidRuntime(626): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
03-15 12:08:34.409: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3591)
03-15 12:08:34.409: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
03-15 12:08:34.409: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
03-15 12:08:34.409: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
03-15 12:08:34.409: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-15 12:08:34.409: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-15 12:08:34.409: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
03-15 12:08:34.409: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-15 12:08:34.409: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-15 12:08:34.409: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
03-15 12:08:34.409: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-15 12:08:34.409: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-15 12:08:34.409: E/AndroidRuntime(626): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
03-15 12:08:34.409: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-15 12:08:34.409: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-15 12:08:34.409: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3586)
03-15 12:08:34.409: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  ... 11 more
03-15 12:08:34.409: E/AndroidRuntime(626): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
03-15 12:08:34.409: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
03-15 12:08:34.409: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
03-15 12:08:34.409: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
03-15 12:08:34.409: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
03-15 12:08:34.409: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
03-15 12:08:34.409: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
03-15 12:08:34.409: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
03-15 12:08:34.409: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
03-15 12:08:34.409: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
03-15 12:08:34.409: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
03-15 12:08:34.409: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
03-15 12:08:34.409: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at com.example.test.MainActivity.test_button(MainActivity.java:55)
03-15 12:08:34.409: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  ... 14 more
```

What is wrong here? Can someone see the problem?

edit: When I try to access my php file with my browser I get this Message :

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''name','points') VALUES('','')' at line 1

Comment: Your MySQL error is a missing space after my_table and before the parenthesis.

Comment: You also are vulnerable to mysql injection and need to use mysqli_* functions as mysql_* is deprecated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem with your App is, that you use network functions in your main-Thread. Try to use something like an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

If you access your PHP-file with your browser you have to make sure that your post-values aren't empty.

Comment: Why is sth. like this not available in the Main thread ? So should I just paste the code into a async task class ?

Comment: Networking, espacially on a mobile device, is an verry unsave thing. It could take hours to complete. The main-Thread is in a permanent loop with a WatchDog-Timer integrated to check if everything is ok. So you can't do things on it which take a lot of time. For the AsyncTask just follow the Example in the reference

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is the uncaught **NetworkOnMainThreadException** which is well documented - Google for it. Basically you need to do all network comms  in an AsyncTask.

Also the link you gave doesn't work (even with http)

Comment: If you want to pass values via the URL then you need to use $_GET instead of $_POST

Comment: @amaster507. You are correct, I'm used to dealing with forms. Edited answer